# Display error fields from HttpRequestValidationException in custom page after redirect?

Tags: asp.net

I want to be able to display to the user the field(s) that have illegal characters in them
Currently I have the below code in the Global.asax file which redirect to a cusom error page if HttpRequestValidationException is true.

```
 protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();

        if (ex is HttpRequestValidationException)
        {
            Response.Redirect("IllegalCharactersError.aspx?error=");              
        }
    }
```

Thanks
Darren

Comment: Wouldn't this feeback to the user make it easier to craft a request to exploit your site. Perhaps it makes more sense to just validate your inputs before the post.

Comment: Hi - Not everyfield has validation but even fields with validation the error is initially caught but then proceeds to the "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected" page which I have a custom page for. Cheers.